# How to dynamically generate Shiny sidebarPanel contents?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I'm trying to create an app where the user is initially presented with a sidebar `selectInput` containing a list of choices: A, B, C and D – populated by file-system contents.

Depending on which choice the user selects, I want to populate the rest of the sidebar with choice-specific contents. For example, if the user chooses "A", then the sidebar will contain an additional `selectInput` and `dateRangeInput`.

To keep the code clean, I've kept all "A"-specific code in `handle_A.R`, etc. This means that eventually when I decide to add a new choice "E", I just need to put all the code in `handle_E.R`.

**ui.R**

```
pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Test"),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectizeInput("choice", "Choice:", c()),
    uiOutput("sidebar")
  ),
  mainPanel(uiOutput("main"))
)
```

**server.R** (relevant bits)

```
output$sidebar <- renderUI({
  sidebarRenderer[[input$choice]](input, output, session)
})
```

I have code in `server.R` that sources all the `handle_*.R` scripts – each registering their callbacks.

So far, so good. I can select various choices and the relevant callbacks are called. However, I don't know how to implement the callbacks such that I can update the sidebar widgets as the user interacts with the sidebar. I want to essentially do the following (which will not work, because the function needs to return something to `renderUI`):

**handle_A.R**

```
sidebarRenderer[["A"]] <<- function(input, output, session) {
  selectInput("day", "Day:", c("Mon", "Wed", "Fri"))
  dates <- getDateList(input$day)
  dateRangeInput("date", "Date:", start=dates[0], end=dates[length(dates)])
  if (hasPublicHoliday(dates))
    checkboxInput("ignoreHolidays", "Ignore public holidays")
}
```

So what I want is to automatically update `dateRangeInput` to the calculated start and end dates for the corresponding Mon/Wed/Fri. Furthermore, if any of the dates contain a public holiday, I want to display an extra checkbox to let the user ignore public holidays.

If anybody can help me out, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Can you make the full, runnable application available as a Gist? I don't understand the architecture of the app you're describing.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, but I figured it out using `observe` and `updateCheckboxInput`.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all I needed was to put the logic in `observe` and call `updateCheckBoxInput`.